# Add Months to Data Frame using a period column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm looking to add a %Y%m%d date column to my dataframe using a period column that has integers 1-32, which represent monthly data points starting at a defined environment variable "odate" (e.g. if odate=20190531 then period 1 should be 20190531, period 2 should be 20190630, etc.)

I tried defining a dictionary with the number of periods in the column as the keys and the value being odate + MonthEnd(period -1)

This works fine and well; however, I want to improve the code to be flexible given changes in the number of periods.

Is there a function that will allow me to fill the date columns with the odate in period 1 and then subsequent month ends for subsequent periods?

example dataset:

odate=20190531

```
period value
1      5.5
2      5
4      6.2
3      5
5      40
11     5
```

desired dataset:

odate=20190531

```
period value date
1      5.5   2019-05-31
2      5     2019-06-30
4      6.2   2019-08-31
3      5     2019-07-31
5      40    2019-09-30
11     5     2020-03-31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.date_range()`:

```
pd.date_range(start = '2019-05-31', periods = 100,freq='M')
```

You can change total periods depending on what you need, the `freq='M'` means a Month-End frequency

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) is a list of Offset Aliases you can for `freq` parameter.

If you just want to add or subtract some period to a date you can use `pd.DataOffset`:

```
odate = pd.Timestamp('20191031')
odate
>> Timestamp('2019-10-31 00:00:00')

odate - pd.DateOffset(months=4)
>> Timestamp('2019-06-30 00:00:00')

odate + pd.DateOffset(months=4)
>> Timestamp('2020-02-29 00:00:00')
```

To add given the period column to Month Ends:

```
odate = pd.Timestamp('20190531')
df['date'] = df.period.apply(lambda x: odate + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(x-1))
df
 period value   date
0   1   5.5     2019-05-31
1   2   5.0     2019-06-30
2   4   6.2     2019-08-31
3   3   5.0     2019-07-31
4   5   40.0    2019-09-30
5   11  5.0     2020-03-31
```

To improve performance use `list-comprehension`:

```
df['date'] = [odate + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(period-1) for period in df.period]
```

Comment: one issue with this method is that the "period" column may be out of order in my dataset (e.g. first row could show period 4, which would need to be tagged still as 20191031 if odate is defined as 20190530)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean, adding the month period 4 to the original date?

Comment: no so my dataset is tagged with a period column that is unsorted. my script will have a defined odate variable which will _always_ correspond to period 1 of my dataset. I want to create a new column that tags all periods in the dataset with the corresponding month end date relative to the odate

Comment: Hmm it will be easier to understand if you could add some relevant sample data.